# does there exist a positive integer $X$ such that none of the integers $1+X,2+X,\ldots,x+X$ is the power of a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

For which positive integers $x$ does there exist a positive integer $X$ such that none of the integers $1+X,2+X,\ldots,x+X$ is the power of a prime number?

So this question is kinda confusing to understand so i started to interpret the question

Let 11 be a prime number:

so the powers of $11$ are $11^1, 11^2,11^3,\ldots$ and so on but i just dont get what the question is asking.

Does anyone know what this question is asking?

Comment: Yes, I know what the question is asking. It's asking, for which values of $x$ does there exist a positive integer $X$ such that none of the numbers $1+X,2+X,\dots,x+X$ is a power of a prime number. (For instance, $x=2$ is such a number, because we can take $X=13$ and neither of the numbers $1+X=14$ and $2+X=15$ is a power of a prime number.)

Comment: Hint: you can solve the problem by showing that **every** positive integer $x$ has the stated property. In other words, for every positive integer $x$, you can find $x$ consecutive integers none of which is a power of a prime. (Have you learned the Chinese Remainder Theorem?)

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, the question is asking for which positive integers $x$ it is true that there exist $x$ consecutive positive integers, none of which is a prime power. For example, $x=1$ easily satisfies this. As pointed out inthe comments, $x=2$ satisfies this, as well. Also, $x=3$ satisfies this, since none of $20,21,22$ is a prime power.

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation is: What are the possible gaps between prime powers?

A related question is: Does the gap go to infinity?

Here are the smallest examples for gaps of size $x$ for $1 \le x \le 25$:

```
x   X   1+X x+X
1   5   6   6
2   13  14  15
3   19  20  22
4   32  33  36
5   53  54  58
6   89  90  95
7   89  90  96
8   97  98  105
9   97  98  106
10  97  98  107
11  97  98  108
12  97  98  109
13  97  98  110
14  97  98  111
15  97  98  112
16  97  98  113
17  97  98  114
18  97  98  115
19  97  98  116
20  97  98  117
21  97  98  118
22  97  98  119
23  97  98  120
24  128 129 152
25  128 129 153
```

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111029/prime-power-gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_x, q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_x$ be primes.

so $p_1q_1, p_2q_2, \ldots, p_xq_x$ are relatively primes.

By Chinese remainder theorem, there exists $X$ such that

$X \equiv -1 (\bmod{p_1q_1})$

$X \equiv -2 (\bmod{p_2q_2})$

.

.

$X \equiv -x (\bmod{p_xq_x})$

we obtain $X+1, X+2, \ldots, X+x$ is not a power of a prime.

Comment: @lhf, is there any error in my answer ? Thank you.